# WPF Inheritance Context inside a ResourceDictionary

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to apply the freezable trick that's described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2008/05/21/model-see_2c00_-model-do.aspx) to get an inheritance context from an object that's not in the visual tree.

This works for my freezables when they are defined in the XAML of the window (placed in the resource dictionary of the window). What I want to do now is to put them into an external resource dictionary XAML so that I can use them from multiple controls.

Here's sample code of the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TestWpfApp.MainWindow">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Strings.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <WpfExtensions:StringResource x:Key="TestResourceInWindowXaml" ResId="TestResource" />
        </ResourceDictionary>            
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel Margin="8">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, Source={StaticResource TestResourceInWindowXaml}}" />              <- Works!
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, Source={StaticResource TestResourceInExternalXaml}}" />            <- Doesn't work!
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

For the TestResourceInWindowXaml-object it works perfectly, the InheritanceContext is set to the window. It doesn't work for the TestResourceInExternalXaml which is defined in the merged resource dictionary, though: the InheritanceContext-property of this freezable is always null.

Is this possible at all?
Is there any trick to work around this?